# CentOS 7 Linking sites in Apache conf folders without using a2ensite and a2dissiste

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I'm following [this guide](https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/) to create virtualhosts in my server, but my apache is running on CentOS 7, and I do not have the a2ensite command required at point 5.

What's the equivalent centos command for the command the guide uses at point 5 ?

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite ostechnix1.lan.conf
sudo a2ensite ostechnix2.lan.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7 distributes additional Apache configurations at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf`.

An equivalent of `sudo a2ensite ostechnix1.lan.conf` could be `mv ostechnix1.lan.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

To emulate `a2dissite`, remove the specified configuration file from `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.

Apache needs to be restarted after changing configurations.